# ngroute change master page for specific route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, ngroute

I want to know if its possible to change the master page which is used by ngroute for specific pages. For example, I want to display different master page or exclude completely the master page for specific pages but still maintain the url structure.

Example:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
            controller: "homeController",
            templateUrl: "/views/home/index.html"
        })
        .when("/ourteam", {
            templateUrl: "/views/home/our-team.html",
            title: "Our Team"
        })
        .when("/login", {
            templateUrl: "/views/home/login.html",
            title: "Login",
            countroller: "loginController"
        });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Url redirect works fine but the actual layout is messed up because the login page has different markup. Is it possible to switch to another master page for specific pages?

Answer (score 0):

If you want different Layout for different routes than I guess you have to switch from **ngRoute** to **uiRouter** as uiRouter is more flexible in terms of creating routes and associating views to it.

There is a very nice tutorial given by Tim Kindberg on youtube for the same, I am sharing the link below just go through it.

**Link:**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqJRoh8MnBo